# Number of likes via Facebook tab on client's fan page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, fan-page

I wanted to know if there was any way to accurately get the number of new likes that came in due to a Facebook tab that has a like gate installed(coded) on a Client's Fan Page.

As part of analytics, I wanted to show that here are the number of likes that were generated by users visiting this tab by hitting the "Like" button present on top of the fan page on facebook.com.

Having a iframe like widget on my tab is not an option... I know this can be tracked. They need to click the "Like" button on the fan page itself. I code in PHP.

**UPDATE**

I do not want to use Sessions on my tab. It is a simple call-to-action tab and Safari has issues with 3rd party cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Through the `signed_request` you have access to whether or not the user visiting the page tab has liked the page or not.

And since liking the page reloads the page tab, you should easily be able to trace the transition from *has not liked* to *has liked the page* in your session, and then take appropriate action to log this “event” wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the facebook javascript SDK in your page to detect whether the user has LIKED the page whilst browsing the fan page. You could then use AJAX to store into a file/database

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'INSERT APP ID',
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth: true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });

        //Additional
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
           alert('Put AJAX Code Here');
        });
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
            ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
```

Hope this helps... 
http://www.skruffymedia.com/blog/creating-a-facebook-like-gate-competition/

Comment: This would work only if we have a like button on my webpage but I am looking to get the likes from the "Like" button present on top of the fan page on facebook.com.